# How to identify which cell(s)/column(s) have Filters set?

Tags: c#, excel, interop, cell

I am using Microsoft Interop to read the data.

In excel-sheet, multiple random columns have "filters" set. How do I find out which cells /columns have filters set? I would like lo load only the columns that have filters set.

here is how the sheet looks like

row 1-5,  col 1-10 [long text describes the data in the sheet, i do not want to load ]

row 1-10, col 1 [some data, not filtered, i do not want to load]

row 1-10, col 2-15 [filter set for some columns only, i would like to detect the filters and load the entire column data ]

Comment: Please don't prefic your titles with "C# Excel Interop:" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `Worksheet` interface has an `AutoFilter` property that returns an `AutoFilter` interface.
- The `AutoFilter` interface has a `Filters` property that returns a `Filters` interface.
- The `AutoFilter` interface has a `Range` property that returns the range being filtered.
- The `Filters` interface is a collection of `Filter`s; these are in the same order as the columns in `AutoFilter.Range`
- The `Filter` interface has an `On` property that indicates whether the column is being filtered.